# How to make cart & checkout page calculation in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Actually, i'm working on opencart 2.3, if now checkout page calculation in opencart:

```
Sub-Total₹ 1,520.00
India Shipping₹ 180.00
Discount (-07%)₹ -119.00
Total₹ 1,581.00

it s taking discount in shipping amount also i don't want discount shipping amount, i want calculation like this please help. 

Sub-Total₹ 1,520.00
Discount (-07%)₹ -106.40
India Shipping₹ 180.00
Total₹ 1,593.60
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to do? Your question lacks some elementary elements. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change in admin>extensions>extensions>Order totals... sort order for the shipping. Move it down by changing sort order number higher than your discount voucher.